# How to remotely connect to another Gnome Boxes VM?

Tags: ssh, gnome-boxes

I'm not too familiar with SSH things, and I'm trying to do a remote connection to a virtual machine on my other PC which has Gnome Boxes installed on it.

**Might be a simple question, but are there any commands to run to see my SSH status, and how can I connect to my remote Gnome Box?**

I'm essentially trying to find a way to obtain the address of my other box (the ssh://xxxx address) in order to connect remotely to my Gnome box of another device.

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: could you explain what you mean with "SSH status"? Can you ssh into the machine running the VMs? You could use that as a "jump host" to then SSH into the VMs.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, I'm trying to connect to a Gnome Boxes VM via SSH. I'm sorry if I wasn't more specific. I'm trying to connect to a Gnome Boxes VM from another Linux device, and am unsure of how to obtain the address of the other box in order to remotely connect to it. (such as finding out the address: ssh://xxxxxxxx)

Comment: Again, there probably is no such address, you will need to jump through the machine that's running the virtual machines.

Comment: I will answer your question, but I need my other machine, which has the needed information. Give me some time.